# jetbrains-toolbox loads to a blank screen

Tags: arch-linux, java, troubleshooting

For the last month or so, I've been attempting to get jetbrains-toolbox to work. It used to work (and is how I installed IntelliJ IDEA and Gogland.) When I went to update the IDEA

I'm currently using Arch. Here are the things I have tried.

1. Loading jetbrains-toolbox from within Sway.
2. Reinstalling jetbrains-toolbox from the aur.
3. Reinstalling jetbrains-toolbox from the Jetbrains website.
4. Launching it with --disable-gpu
5. Clearing ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox
6. Googling all messages that I get.
7. Loading jetbrains-toolbox in different DEs. I tried GNOME, KDE, and i3.

The settings file (~/local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/.settings.json), even after being cleared by action number 5, is able to regenerate, so I assume that there is something, somewhere on my filesystem that it isn't going away. This is what I think might be causing the problems. I have verified that the settings file was deleted by looking at Thunar's trash folder. However, doing a search for my email address (contained in the settings file) from ripgrep did not turn up anything relevant.

These are the commands I ran:

1. `cd ~/
   sudo rg --hidden "MY_EMAIL_HERE" >> ~/Desktop/home_search.txt`
2. `cd /usr/ 
   sudo rg --hidden "MY_EMAIL_HERE" >> ~/Desktop/home_search.txt`

The only relevant results of this were: 
`.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/.settings.json:        "email": "MY_EMAIL_HERE",
.local/share/Trash/files/Toolbox/.settings.json:        "email": "MY_EMAIL_HERE",`

I'm not exactly proficient with Linux, but I've been asking around for help with this for a while. If you have any advice, please have patience with me. I might be a bit stupid.

When I run it from the terminal, this is the message that shows up:

`john@john ~/D/jetbrains-toolbox-1.2.2314> ./jetbrains-toolbox 
[0415/155414:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(311)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale`

This is a message that will show up occasionally *through a system tray notification* (it does not use my notification daemon):

`failed to find application to url: share/jetbrains-toolbox/jetbrains-toolbox`

Maybe I need some folder in /usr/share or ~/.local/share named jetbrains-toolbox? I *do not* have that folder in either location.

These are two log files. One is from executing ToolBox and leaving it open for a bit. Another is from uninstalling ToolBox from the aur and deleting ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox and leaving it open for a bit. They have been labeled appropriately. https://gist.github.com/gonzalezjo/4cf09eb4b7ad849df5557fd297a7061c

When I open ToolBox, I'm greeted with a black screen. After about 15 seconds, it becomes white. Here's an imgur gallery showcasing this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9vxf.jpg

(Note: I don't have enough reputation to include these as separate images while still including a link to the logs. Sorry about that :\)

From the moment the black screen shows to the moment it becomes white, I've timed it down to an average of 13.7 seconds using a stopwatch app on my phone and three trials. From the moment I type ./jetbrains-toolbox to the moment it becomes white, it's an average of about 16.1 seconds. Again, three trials.

My CPU is a Haswell i7 (i7-4790k) and my GPU is Pascal (Nvidia's GTX 1050). I think it's possible that this could be graphics driver or X related (or both? I am clueless here.) based off of a scary experience upgrading drivers prevented me from entering a DE. That experience was resolved after xorg (or something like that?) and the `nvidia` package were reinstalled.

According to nvidia-smi, my driver version is:

`NVIDIA-SMI 378.13                 Driver Version: 378.13`

I've tried to provide all the information I can, but if anything else is needed, I'm happy to provide.

Comment: It will be fixed in .5xxx release by Jetbrains. I even linked the bug task from their tracker to Arch forums.

Answer (score 14):

Just launch with `--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox` and it should work.

I found it in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229859

Answer (score 2):

So I spent about a month struggling with packages and downloads everywhere, with tons of googling, asking around etc., to no avail. I made this post and within about an hour, messing around in my file manager, completely clueless, I somehow managed to fix this. Welp. Sorry...  Here's exactly what I did. Hurray for desperation, I guess?

1. Install the `jetbrains-toolbox` package from the AUR.
2. Go to `/opt/JetBrains/Toolbox` (found by looking at the `PKGBUILD`)
3. Navigate to `/opt/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/` to find `jetbrains-toolbox`, an executable. I copied this to a folder I made in documents named `ToolboxResearch/`.
   (Run `mkdir -p ~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted`, then run `cp /opt/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/jetbrains-toolbox ~/Documents/ToolboxResearch`).
4. Navigate to `~/Documents/ToolboxResearch`
5. Extract it using Ark to the `Extracted` folder.
6. You should have a file hierarchy that looks like so: `~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/`. I copied this from the file path bar of Thunar, my file manager of choice, so if I made a mistake anywhere up to this point, you can rest assured that this part is correct.
7. To avoid confusing myself with `/usr/` and `usr/`, I ran `mv ~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/usr ~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/store`.
8. I edited `~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/Jetbrains Toolbox` to have these contents:

   ```
   Type=Application
   Name=JetBrains Toolbox
   Exec=/home/john/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/store/bin/jetbrains-toolbox %u
   Icon=/store/share/jetbrains-toolbox/toolbox.svg
   StartupNotify=false
   Terminal=true
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/jetbrains;
   ```

   The changes I made are specifically limited to `Exec`, `Icon`, and `Terminal`. I changed `Terminal` to `true` just to see what it did and I changed `Icon` and `Exec` to reflect the new file paths. I highly doubt that this did anything though.

   You will want to change "john" to reflect your home directory instead of mine.
9. I opened `~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/store/bin/jetbrains-toolbox` (again, copy-pasting from Thunar) in my editor and edited line 5, which starts with `path=`. I changed it to `path=~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/store/share/$app`.
10. Navigated to `~/Documents/ToolboxResearch/Extracted/jetbrains-toolbox/store/bin/` in my terminal.
11. Ran `./jetbrains-toolbox`
12. It worked!

Sorry for making this post. I Never would've thought that I'd figure this out so soon after I made it. I actually thought I was hopeless.

If someone has this problem and can't fix it even after reading this, you can leave a reply and I'll hopefully be able to help you out. My apologies if this explanation wasn't very clear.